# show one line per second in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to show one line per second in javascript, but it is not working...

https://jsfiddle.net/d9a784ta/

```
function showIt1() {
  document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function showIt2() {
  document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function showIt3() {
  document.getElementById("div3").style.visibility = "visible";
}

window.onload = function() {
setTimeout("showIt1()", 1000);
setTimeout("showIt2()", 2000);
setTimeout("showIt3()", 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `display` property with `block` value, because it overwrites the initial `display: none`.

For using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), you could insert the reference to the function, without using strings and supply the parameter for the `id` and use only one function.

```js
function showIt(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}

window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(showIt, 1000, 'div1');
    setTimeout(showIt, 2000, 'div2');
    setTimeout(showIt, 3000, 'div3');
};
```

```css
#div1, #div2, #div3 { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="div1"><h1>1 line</h1></div>
<div id="div2"><h1>2 line</h1></div>
<div id="div3"><h1>3 line</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the function directly, not with a string:

```
function showIt1() {
  document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function showIt2() {
  document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function showIt3() {
  document.getElementById("div3").style.visibility = "visible";
}

window.onload = function() {
setTimeout(showIt1, 1000);
setTimeout(showIt2, 2000);
setTimeout(showIt3, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In setTimeout, you provide first argument as string. It should be a name of function, like this:

```
setTimeout(showIt1, 1000);
```

So, it all would look like:

```
function showIt1() {
  document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function showIt2() {
  document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function showIt3() {
  document.getElementById("div3").style.visibility = "visible";
}

window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(showIt1, 1000);
  setTimeout(showIt2, 2000);
  setTimeout(showIt3, 3000);
}
```

---

setTimeout() accepts *Function* as it's first parameter. When you create a function called **showIt1**, then when you for example write to the console something like this:

```
console.log(showIt1)
```

It will output: "Function". So that's why you are also allowed to call setTimeout() like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "visible";
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1) changed `document.getElementById` for JQquery `$("#id")`

2) added quotes on your `<div>` ids

3) using .css() function:

HTML:

```
<div id="div1"><h1>1 line</h1></div>
<div id="div2"><h1>2 line</h1></div>
<div id="div3"><h1>3 line</h1></div>
```

JS:

```
function showIt1() {
  $("#div1").css('display','block');
}
function showIt2() {
  $("#div2").css('display','block');
}
function showIt3() {
 $("#div3").css('display','block');
}

window.onload = function() {
console.log('onload');
setTimeout("showIt1()", 1000);
setTimeout("showIt2()", 2000);
setTimeout("showIt3()", 3000);
}
```

JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/dudu84/d9a784ta/2/